# Group more than one regular expression in the same command

Tags: unix, solaris, solaris-10

How to group two regular expression in one command

example if have a file like:

```
age22
Helwan University Engineering Faculty
ITI-intake33
bye FOr NOW
i am mahmoud 34
mie 4
a
```

And I want to search for the line that start with by and end with W ???

Using **grep** command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need more than one regular expression for this.

```
grep '^by.*W$' filename.txt
```

should suffice.

Comment: why you use `.*` before W ???
I tried `'^by.W$'` and didn't work,
I am beginner in UNIX

Comment: It works with be, and I'll accept your answer after 9 minutes the site told me that