# Remove numbers within brackets only

Tags: bash, sed

How can I remove numbers within brackets only?
For example, I have the following text:

```
This is 14 April [988] text..
```

I would like to remove the `[988]` and leave `14` intact.

What i've tried so far:

```
sed 's@\[[0-9]\]@@g'
```

Comment: So close! `sed 's@\[[0-9]*\]@@g'`

Comment: It's funny how people don't get this especially today. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12921217/group-more-than-one-regular-expression-in-the-same-command/12921253#12921253

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

On Mac:

```
sed -E 's@\[[0-9]+\]@@g'
```

On Linux:

```
sed -r 's@\[[0-9]+\]@@g'
```

Comment: +1 for you, best answer so far. But come on, don't downvote me choking on `sed`'s flags!

Comment: @H2CO3: I haven't downvoted any answer (I very rarely down vote any answer, I merely comment to let people know)

Answer (score 3):

You need to enable *repeating* (multiple) numerical characters in order to get this work - as it stands, your regex will remove only single-digit numbers. If you want numbers composed of at least one (one or more) numerical characters, try

```
sed -E 's/\[[0-9]+\]//g'
```

Comment: @anubhava probably the text to be replaced contains slashes? What if you try with your original `@` delimiter? (I just use a slash because I'm used to it.)

Comment: Original text is: `'This is 14 April [988] text'`

Comment: Let's see after edit: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4960980/Screen%20Shot%202012-10-16%20at%209.26.03%20PM.png

Answer (score 1):

This should work (added the escaped `+`)

```
sed 's@\[[0-9]\+\]@@g'
```

Comment: sed by default uses basic regular expression (BRE) which requires `\+` for it to mean "1 or more". I just tried and it works

Comment: see anubhava's answer, IMHO it's the best one here.

Comment: @doubleDown ERE's interpret the escaped + character as a literal `+`.

Comment: Mac's sed doesn't support `+` at all by default?

Comment: @doubleDown: On Mac it needs `-E` switch (i.e. `-r` on Linux)

Comment: @anubhava: Interesting. On Linux it works without any switches as long as you escape it. Mac probably has some old version of sed.

Comment: Yes I know it works on Linux without `-r` switch as well with `\+`.